# Git conflicted files

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-stash

I am having a problem with git merge / rebase and even stash, let me explain what is happening:

Situation:
I and other friend, we are working in separate branches, but we have a file that we always modify (messages.properties). Who finishes the work first, commit and push and the other make a fetch, stash his work, merge the branch with the branch´s friend and apply the stash ... here we always have a problem, because my messages.properties override his messages, and his modifications are lost.

The situation above happens even when I commit my work (instead of stash) and rebase /merge with his work; my messages always override his modifications.

I don´t know what I am doing wrong here, someone can help me?

Comment: What is this file good for? Sure, that it should be versioned?

Comment: what commands are you using to achieve the workflow you mention? Maybe the issue lies in the exact commands used.

Comment: @KingCrunch This file is for internationalization!

Comment: @D-Rock I am using eGit from Eclipse ...

Comment: @DiegoGusava OK, sounds like it should be versioned. Consider splitting it into pieces, so everyone of you have separate files (such as one messages-file per module or so)

Comment: @KingCrunch sorry, but the file is versioned!

Comment: @DiegoGusava What I (previously) wanted to say: For some configuration files (or similar) it is best practice to not commit the concrete file, but a template like `messages.properties.dist`. When you setup your workspace you copy the file to `messages.properties` and edit it regarding your (local) needs. However, like already mentioned it seems that this isn't appropiate here.

Comment: Isn't there some log where you can see what eGit is actually doing under the hood?

Comment: @JiříPospíšil No, I can´t :(

Answer (score 0):

Do this from the command line. You can see what changed with `git log -p --graph --all -- path/to/messages.properties`